# Is the word “恶犬” trending IRL?

Tags: mandarin

I’m seeing pet shops around hanging up signs with:

> 恶犬

in many places.

This is not something I’ve noticed on quite a large scale, like this, before.

It’s real world data, so harder to track online.

I’m not really sure how to go about searching something like this.

Any ideas?

Is the word “恶犬” trending?

Comment: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=%E6%81%B6%E7%8A%AC - I suppose it gives a reflection of what happens in the real world.

Comment: I think it was trending online first, the sign you see is probably a result of some sign merchant monitoring baidu trends. Do a Google image search of 恶犬 and you'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track the trend of a word in real world, especially when this word may not be popular in a large area or on the Internet, you should do it yourself. Ask local residents living around, or these shop keepers who decided to use this word to find out the reason behind. Maybe looking up local newspaper also helps.

“恶犬” (fierce dog) is not a new word, I think it's mostly used around factories or private properties to warn irrelevant people to keep away. It’s seen in rural areas more often. I hardly saw it used by pet shops (and I think they should use "lovely dog" instead). Interesting if it can be confirmed as a new trend.